# Prove that if an integer $n$ is odd, then there exists some integer $c$ such that $n^2 = 4c + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

So far, since we know that $n$ is an odd integer, we can set $n = 2k + 1$ by definition of odd integers.

Now we have $$(2k + 1)^2 = 4c + 1 \implies k^2 + k = c$$

and I am currently stuck on the step highlighted above.

Comment: I don't know what step is highlighted. But what about expanding $(2k+1)^2$ and defining $c$ such that it makes sense?
Also, I don't understand what you mean by the equal sign in the parentheses.

Comment: Let $n=2k+1$.  Then $n^2 = (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2+4k+1 = 4(\underbrace{\dots}_{\text{call this }~c})+1$

Comment: note that $n^2 = 4c + 1$ is equivalent to $n^2 - 1^2 = 4c$

Answer (score 3):

You're nearly done. As you said, if $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$. 
So $$n^2=4k^2+4k+1=4(k^2+k)+1=4c+1$$
So $c=k^2+k$ satisfies the equation. So all you should do is just eliminate the $4$ when you are simplifying.

Answer (score 2):

More is true:

If $n$ is odd 
there exists $c$ such that
$n^2 = 8c+1$.

Proof:

Since $n$ is odd,
$n = 2m+1$
so that
$n^2
= (2m+1)^2
=4m^2+4m+1
=4m(m+1)+1
$.

Whether $m$ is even or odd,
$m+1$ has opposite parity,
so $m(m+1)$
is even.

Therefore,
if we let
$c = \dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}$,
then
$c$ is an integer and
$n^2 
= 8c+1$.

Comment: You realize that you've just said 2=1, right? If n^2 equals both 4c+1 and 8c+1, then we can set them equal to each other, subtract one from both sides, and divide both sides by 4c to get 2=1. So obviously something is wrong: how can n^2 equal both?

Comment: @DonielF: You realize that $c$ in this proof is not the same as $c$ in the original statement?

Comment: Yup. It's half.